# Modify recurring text/string in txt file based on matching text/parameter(s)

Tags: batch, regex, vbscript

I have a text file named example.txt, which contains:

```
[{
      "Subtitle": {
        "Search": {
          "Burn": false,
          "Default": false,
          "Enable": false,
          "Forced": false
        },
        "SubtitleList": [
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 2,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 1
          },
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 3,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 2
        }]
    }
}]
```

However, this can be repeated multiple times throughout the txt file, always following the same basic structure.

Under **"SubtitleList"**, I want to make sure that it is always the case that **"Default": true**, while **"ID": 1** and **"Track": 0**.

Else If ID and Track equal anything else ( e.g. "ID": 2 and "Track": 1 or something similar), then default should be false.

I think this needs a for loop, or an if then else and run from a Batch file.

I also think that for this to work correctly, the code *may* need to check the entire contents within the { } brackets under each "SubtitleList" section (but I am not totally sure about this).

**Something like this *(pseudocode)*:**

```
if
        "SubtitleList": [
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": false,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
          },
then
        "SubtitleList": [
          {
            "Burn": false,
            "Default": true,
            "Forced": false,
            "ID": 1,
            "Offset": 0,
            "Track": 0
          },         
else
do nothing
```

The **"Default"** should only equal **'true' while "ID": 1** and **"Track": 0** else it should always be 'false'.

I would rather use a Batch file than Powershell (if that is possible), or open to other possible suggestions like VBScript.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I know you also say you don't want to use PowerShell but I wanted to mention you can embed PS logic right into a batch script and it'll work for the need as if it were a batch script and transparently too. I've written other answers on SU with this technique but here's a snippet of correlated PS logic that would set the `default to true` if it were not while `id = 1` and `track = 0` for example: https://pastebin.com/zbNkAFUq. I'd use PS since it have built in Json support or else VB logic may get complex or batch malform the Json, etc. I'd need to expand of this to scale dynamically obviously.

Comment: Under 'SubtitleList' - "The "Default" should equal 'true' while "ID": 1 and "Track": 0 else "Default" should be 'false'", this is the scenario to take precedent.

Comment: I looked at the code example, but I think the if statement needs to be run through a for loop (?) as there is likely to be more than one instance of 'SubtitleList' appearing in the file.

Comment: Yes, and thus it needs to be able to dynamically scale.... I'll see if I can get something tested after work later to expand on this logic and it'll likely be a loop for sure. Just wanted to make sure you were fine with it first before I sent time on it.

Comment: Yes I just wasn't quite sure if the array on its own e.g. Subtitle.SubtitleList[0] was enough to make it work but I didn't think so. I have also updated the code sample above to show how it looks with more "ID" and "Track" under the SubtitleList section.

Comment: Here's the latest I have that should work but I cannot figure it out 100% but it's close.... https://pastebin.com/2byPzRqK. I left the commented out enumerator logic in there if you want to play with it in PS ISE to see it populate accordingly once the variables are set.  The conditions are hitting fine it seems iterating over the index but it cannot update default and get's error *"The property 'Default' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set"*.... I've run out of time for today but see if that helps (.....)

Comment: This might be another pointer to get deeper with it but not sure and out of time I can help for the day https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2011/09/powershell-v3-creating-objects-with-pscustomobject-its-fast.html — I'll check back in with you tomorrow.